# Custom tab in file properties dialog

Tags: c++, .net, windows, windows-explorer

I want to show some additional info in file properties dialog in Windows for some specified types. For example, add new tab "Summary" for *.txt files and show there number of words, number of lines, etc.

I can use C++ and C#. But file summary is collected by .NET library, so I'd prefer to delegate this task to .NET to the extent possible.

Comment: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/powerext-adds-net-tab-to-windows-explorers-file-properties-dialog/ its open source so you can check it out in the code. Subversion also does this so you could check out their source code too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a tab to default Properties' window of image files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990859/adding-a-tab-to-default-properties-window-of-image-files)

Comment: Thanks a lot, **RedX**! And yes, this question is really the duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Michale Dunn has written a series of articles on [shell extensions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/830/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens), Part V dealing with custom property pages.